# llvm : linking debug + assert library to libLTO.so failed

Tags: llvm

I am using `ubntu-12.10 32-bit` system, on which while building `llvm`, it failed on
error: `llvm : linking debug + assert library to libLTO.so failed. Signal 9.`

I am using `llvm` for first time, no idea why this happened. Does anyone knows, why this linking failed ?

Comment: Can you paste the exact error from terminal? Which compiler are you using to build llvm ?

Comment: @mishr: while in process to find answer, I lost that error. I will post soon once I am done with building of `llvm`. Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found!
Sometimes application isn't smart enough to find out CC=PATH & CXX=PATH. 
So while configuration I passed the path for `clag` & `clang++` respectively to `llvm`.
i.e 
`sudo ./configure CC="usr/bin/clang" CXX="/usr/bin/clang++"`

I hope this link may found useful to someone, as I wasted enough time to find problem.